# Primitive Recursive on Some Functions?

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

We took an entrance exam on Set and Complexity Course, The question says:

if $g$ be a `primitive recursive`,

$1)$ $f_1(0)=c_1, f_1(1)=c_2, f_1(x+2)=g(x,f_1(x),f_1(x+1))$, and

$2)$ $f_2(x)=c, f_2(x+1)=g(x,[f_2(0),...,f_2(x)])$ are `primitive recursive`.

> How we can conclude $f_1$ and $f_2$ are Primitive Recursive?

Edit: I thanks from "Carl Mummert" that help me to see [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course-of-values_recursion) for Course-of-values recursion but I‌ caanot adopt it to this example. anyone could point me why these are P.R.?

Comment: Please use only the most relevant tags. "Computer science" should not be used for all computability questions - only those that are specifically related to computer science. This problem is not about set theory or computational complexity at all.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the question? What have you tried? These questions are the sort of thing that would be in almost any textbook - have you looked up "course of values recursion"?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad question in fist review, now it seems good, thanks @CarlMummert

Comment: Did you mean $f_2(0)=c$ instead of $f_2(x)=c$? If $f_2(x)=c$ then $f_2(x+1)$ should be $c$.

Comment: @ZachGershkoff (1) is simple, but (2) is so hard. I think this is True and $f_2(x)=c$.

Comment: I think the (2) in The question already assumes some encoding of sequences [⋯] , and we need one that supports some simple operations that will allow us to implement the course-of-values recursion. Instead of keeping track of a pair $<f_1 (x),f 1 (x+1)>$  as in (1), we must keep track of the entire sequence $[f_2 (0),…,f_2 (x)]$ @ZachGershkoff

Comment: @CarlMummert any references? the (2) is not so simple for me, I dont know others...

Comment: Cross-posted on cs.se: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40768/primitive-recursion-and-course-of-values-recursion-examples.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to take the chance to answer the questions meanwhile refreshing my memory about primitive recursion.

Denote by $[-,-]\colon\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ the pairing function and let $\operatorname{fst}\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}, \operatorname{snd}\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be such that $\operatorname{fst}([x,y])=x, \operatorname{snd}([x,y])=y$. We know that both $[-,-]$, $\operatorname{fst}$ and $\operatorname{snd}$ are primitive recursive.

1. Since $g$ is primitive recursive, function $h:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by $$h(0)=[c_1, c_2], h(x+1) = [\operatorname{snd}(h(x)), g(x, \operatorname{fst}(h(x)), \operatorname{snd}(h(x)))]$$ is primitive recursive using compositions of primitive functions and primitive recursion. Clearly, $h(x) = [f_1(x), f_1(x+1)]$. Hence $f_1(x) = \operatorname{fst}(h(x))$ is primitive recursive.
2. A common way to define $[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$ is to define recursively by setting $[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]:= [[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}], x_n]$ for $n\geq 3$. Under this convention, $\operatorname{snd}[x_1, \ldots, x_n] = x_n$. Back to the question. Since $g$ is primitive recursive, function $h: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $$h(0) = c, h(x+1) = [h(x), g(x,h(x))]$$ is primitive recursive. Clearly, $h(x) = [f_2(0), f_2(1), \dots, f_2(x)]$ and so $f_2(x) = \operatorname{snd}(h(x))$ is primitive recursive.